# Let $x, y, z>0$. Prove that $\left(\lg\frac{y}{z}\right)^{-\lg x}+\left(\lg\frac{z}{x}\right)^{-\lg y}+\left(\lg\frac{x}{y}\right)^{-\lg z} \ge3$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, contest-math

Let $x, y, z>0$. Prove that 
$$\left(\lg\frac{y}{z}\right)^{-\lg x}+\left(\lg\frac{z}{x}\right)^{-\lg y} + \left(\lg\frac{x}{y}\right)^{-\lg z} \ge3$$

Someone can give me a hint? I really have no clue.

Comment: What happens if $\frac{y}{z}<1$?

Comment: Note my corrections to your MathJax code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong. Try $\frac{y}{z}<1$ and $x=2$.

Comment: You are right. I didn't thought about that. Thanks!